# Pushing a git repo to a mapped network Mac drive fails

Tags: git, networking, version-control

I have a Mac 10.8 system on our network where I try to host our repos. On the Mac, I share a directory called 'Repositories'. On my PC, I mapped this directory to Y:

I can indeed clone a repo so it looks like it's working. The problem is that **when I try to push to the remote, it fails to do so**. It says:

```
git -c diff.mnemonicprefix=false -c core.quotepath=false 
push -v --tags --set-upstream origin master:master

Pushing to Y:\Repositories\test.git

remote: error: unable to write sha1 filename 
./objects/e5/08eb4d63d41d2cad4eb782381b3121ab4081b2: 

Permission denied[K
remote: fatal: failed to write object[K
error: unpack failed: unpack-objects abnormal exit
To Y:\Repositories\test.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (unpacker error)
error: failed to push some refs to 'Y:\Repositories\test.git'
```

The thing is that I have another mapped network drive called P: that is working just fine, so it looks like it has to do with the Mac and or rights management.

**Anyone an idea how I can tackle this?**

Comment: Could you try to fire up Filer (or whatever you have on your platform) and try manually create a file under `Y:\Repositories\test.git\objects\e5` directory? And then try to save it. (If this succeedes, delete that file afterwards.) Of course, you have to use the same credentials when doing this your local Git process has when it attemps pushing.

Comment: I mean, try creating a file *there* using a file browsing program *running on your Mac.* That would either confirm or rule out the permissions problem.

Comment: How can I be sure my Git process has the same credentials as Windows Explorer has?

Comment: Ah, right, I'll do that. Just a minute.

Comment: I'm not sure what to do on Mac, but on a Linux-based system, when I mound a CIFS share I specify credentials to authenticate on the remote side *and* local user who has to be granted access to the mounted filesystem.

Comment: I can't. I don't even have rights to open the `Repositories` directory.

Comment: @kostix - How would you handle that?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27009/discussion-between-kostix-and-kriem)